# Does Sitecore Forms meet the standards from WCAG 2.1

Tags: sitecore-forms, accessibility

Do the Sitecore 9 forms meet the standards from WCAG 2.1? I've read that they meet the 2.0 but couldn't find anything around 2.1.

Any documentation that I could have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Sitecore 9 forms do meet WCAG 2.1. If you wish to test this I recommend visiting: https://www.siteimprove.com/glossary/wcag-compliance-checker/